# Error in Mysql Select query with GROUP BY and LIKE operators?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-like, where-in

Following mySql query does not work properly

```
SELECT *
FROM `log`
group by `id`,`domain`
WHERE `domain` LIKE '%facebook%'
```

**but when I remove the  following line it works fine.**

```
group by `id`,`domain`
```

This works properly

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `log`
    WHERE `domain` LIKE '%facebook%'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: While your syntax is legal for MySQL, its result is unpredictable.  Have a look at [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` clause must precede before `GROUP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `log`
WHERE `domain` LIKE '%facebook%'
GROUP BY `id`,`domain`
```

From [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```
[FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found answer myself. **Order should be changed**..

**following works fine.**

```
SELECT *
FROM `log`
WHERE `domain` LIKE '%facebook%'
group by `id`,`domain`
```